# Getting dialogue snippets from text using regular expressions

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to extract snippets of dialogue from a book text. For example, if I have the string

```
"What's the matter with the flag?" inquired Captain MacWhirr. "Seems all right to me."
```

Then I want to extract `"What's the matter with the flag?"` and `"Seem's all right to me."`.

I found a regular expression to use [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/regexbuddy/stringescapedmulti.html), which is `"[^"\\]*(\\.[^"\\]*)*"`. This works great in Eclipse when I'm doing a Ctrl+F find regex on my book .txt file, but when I run the following code:

```
String regex = "\"[^\"\\\\]*(\\\\.[^\"\\\\]*)*\"";
String bookText = "\"What's the matter with the flag?\" inquired Captain MacWhirr. \"Seems all right to me.\""; Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(bookText);

if(m.find())
 System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

The only thing that prints is `null`. So am I not converting the regex into a Java string properly? Do I need to take into account the fact that Java Strings have a `\"` for the double quotes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a natural language text, it's not likely that `"` is escaped by a preceding slash, so you should be able to use just the pattern `"([^"]*)"`.

As a Java string literal, this is `"\"([^\"]*)\""`.

Here it is in Java:

```
String regex = "\"([^\"]*)\"";
String bookText = "\"What's the matter with the flag?\" inquired Captain MacWhirr. \"Seems all right to me.\"";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(bookText);

while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

The above prints:

```
What's the matter with the flag?
Seems all right to me.
```

---

#### On escape sequences

Given this declaration:

```
String s = "\"";
System.out.println(s.length()); // prints "1"
```

The string `s` only has one character, `"`. The `\` is an escape sequence present at the Java source code level; the string itself has no slash.

#### See also

- [JLS 3.10.6 Escape Sequences for Character and String Literals](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.10.6)

---

#### The problem with the original code

There's actually nothing wrong with the pattern per se, but you're not capturing the right portion. `\1` isn't capturing the quoted text. Here's the pattern with the correct capturing group:

```
String regex = "\"([^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\"\\\\]*)*)\"";
String bookText = "\"What's the matter?\" inquired Captain MacWhirr. \"Seems all right to me.\"";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(bookText);

while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

For visual comparison, here's the original pattern, as a Java string literal:

```
String regex = "\"[^\"\\\\]*(\\\\.[^\"\\\\]*)*\""
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                           why capture this part?
```

And here's the modified pattern:

```
String regex = "\"([^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\"\\\\]*)*)\""
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                    we want to capture this part!
```

As mentioned before, though: this complicated pattern isn't necessary for natural language text, which isn't likely to contain escaped quotes.

#### See also

- [regular-expressions.info/Grouping and backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

Comment: Hm, that seems to get everything in between dialogue snippets as well...I only want the dialogue itself.

Comment: @sheldon: please consult the attached the Java code. I think you're confusing the regex pattern with the Java string literal.

Comment: Your `*` is greedy. I think that's what @sheldon mean by it seems to get everything in between snippets. The correct one would be `"([^"]*?)"`

Comment: @Amargosh: the negated character class makes greedy vs reluctant irrelevant: there can only be one match.